# How to download xls file with Angular and Spring Rest Service?

Tags: angularjs, excel, spring-mvc, xslt

I created a factory in angular to call a spring rest service to download xls file.

this is my factory:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('SportsbookServiceCustom', function ($http) {
    return {
        exportToXLS: function () {
            return $http.get('api/sportsbooks/downloadXLS').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I have this code for my rest service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sportsbooks/downloadXLS")
public void downloadXLS(HttpServletResponse response) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 20, Direction.ASC, "id");
    Page<Sportsbook> page = sportsbookRepositoryCustom.findAll(pageable, null, null, null);
    List<Sportsbook> sportsbookList = page.getContent();

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

    Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] { "Emp No.", "Name", "Salary" });
    data.put("2", new Object[] { 1d, "John", 1500000d });
    data.put("3", new Object[] { 2d, "Sam", 800000d });
    data.put("4", new Object[] { 3d, "Dean", 700000d });

    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof Date)
                cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Double)
                cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
        }
    }

    if (workbook != null) {
        // Writing file to outputstream
        try {
            InputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(workbook.getBytes());
            OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentLength((int) (workbook.getBytes().length));

            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=yourFileName.xls");

            IOUtils.copyLarge(fileInputStream, output);
            output.flush();
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs without error but downloading file isn't working. What is error?

Comment: _"What is error?"_ - That's the information we expect from you. Is nothing sent back to the client? Is `response.data` empty? And most importantly,  what do you want to do with the response? `exportToXLS` itself does nothing. If you want a file to be displayed in the browser or saved then simply create a link the user can click on.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `filesaver.js`

Pass the Json from your Server side (here Spring)

```
<div id="exportable">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>DoB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.dob | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

in your angular controller you received items from server eg.below

```
$scope.items = [{
        name: "John Smith",
        email: "j.smith@example.com",
        dob: "1985-10-10"
    }, {
        name: "Jane Smith",
        email: "jane.smith@example.com",
        dob: "1988-12-22"
    }, {
        name: "Jan Smith",
        email: "jan.smith@example.com",
        dob: "2010-01-02"
    }, {
        name: "Jake Smith",
        email: "jake.smith@exmaple.com",
        dob: "2009-03-21"
    }, {
        name: "Josh Smith",
        email: "josh@example.com",
        dob: "2011-12-12"
    }, {
        name: "Jessie Smith",
        email: "jess@example.com",
        dob: "2004-10-12"
    }]
}
```

Add Button Export

```
<button ng-click="exportData()"> Export </button>
```

Define the function in controller

```
$scope.exportData = function () {
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
    };
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/XNVj3/1/)

Comment: i have paggination in my list. How i can make this in server side?